# Meteor Autoform - undesired reload after successful method execution

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using Meteor (1.4.1.2) with AutoForm (5.8.1), and I have a template that is used both for creating and for editing a record in my application (using type=method, where the method name is different if the template is being displayed for creation or edit mode).

```
<template name="exam">
  {{#autoForm schema=form.schema id='examForm' type='method' meteormethod=form.method doc=form.data resetOnSuccess=false}}
    <h3 class='formTitle'><center>{{form.title}}</center></h3>
    <hr>
    {{#if afFieldNames}}
      {{#each afFieldNames}}
        {{#if form.hasImage this.name}} {{> upload }} {{/if}}
        {{#if equals this.name 'requesterName'}} <h3>Dados do paciente</h3> {{/if}}
        {{#if equals this.name 'diseases'}} <hr><h3>Dados do exame</h3> {{/if}}
        {{#if equals this.name 'doctorConclusion'}} <hr><h3>Laudo</h3> {{/if}}
        {{> afQuickField name=this.name}}
      {{/each}}

      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-cancel">Fechar</button>
        {{#if form.hasButtonSubmit}}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
        {{/if}}
      </div>
    {{/if}}

    {{> genericModal title='Exame' modalContext=modalContext }}    
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

The variable form is defined in the Templates onCreated block, and will set variables and schema depending on whether the form is being opened for creating a new record, or for editing an existing record. Method will receive the values either "insertExam" or "updateExam".

In the case of creation of a new record, the form is initialized empty, the user provides input, and upon submit, my defined method runs, and finally the onSuccess hook is called, where a modal with a message and a close button is displayed.

Here are the methods (simplified):

```
Meteor.methods({
    'insertExam': (doc) => {
        // some manipulation before returning (not displayed here)
        return Exam.insert(newExam) && { _id: result, status: newExam.status }
    },

    'updateExam': (doc) => {
        // some manipulation before returning (not displayed here)
        return Exam.update(doc._id, { $set: updatedExam }) && {_id: doc._id, status: updatedExam.status}
    },
});
```

The problem is happening when the form is open for an existing record (edit mode). All info is then read from the collection and displayed. The user may change it, and when submitting, a different method is executed (also with success), the onSuccess hook runs, modal is activated, but for some reason the page is immediately refreshed, so I cannot see the modal on screen.

Here's my template js, where AutoForm hooks are defined:

```
AutoForm.addHooks('examForm', {
    onSuccess: function(formType, result) {
        try {
            var isNew = Router.current().params._id == 'novo' // means record is being created
            var examId = result._id
            if (isNew) {
                modalMessage('Success', 'Exame created with success')
            }
            else if (result) {
                modalMessage('Success', 'Exame updated with success')
            }
        }
    }
}, true);
```

modalMessage is a function that takes care of setting the title/message in the modal, and makes it visible. Just for completness, here's the genericModal template:

```
<template name="genericModal">
  <div class="modal fade" id="genericModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog {{widthClass width}}">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- modal header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
        </div>

        <!-- modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

          <!-- generic message area -->
          <div id="messageArea" hidden="true">
            <p id="messageHeader"><span class="glyphicon" id="modalMessageIcon" aria-hidden="true"></span></p>
            <div id="modalMessage"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modalBtnClose" hidden="true">Fechar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modalBtnOk" disabled>OK</button>
        </div>

      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
</template>
```

I was not able to find where this refresh is coming from. I see no errors in the log. I tried to quickly run step by step, but without deep knowledge of how AutoForm works, it's impossible to follow every line with success.

So for some reason AutoForm is refreshing the page after the execution of onSuccess hook, but only when the form is used for updating, but not for creating a new record (notice that on both cases, autoform with type=method is used).

I've disabled the modal function calls in both creation and edit mode, just to see if it had anythign to do with it, but it doesn't. In creation mode, after onSuccess execution, page stays the same, but on edit mode, after onSuccess, the page is always refreshed.

Anyone have an idea where to look, how to solve it or at least troubleshoot this?

Comment: you should post your code.

Comment: not sure, but maybe you have to return false from your onSubmit(). see here: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#normal (even though i know you're not using type='normal')

Comment: Hi @zim, I think that's not the case, since oSubmit is to be used for performing the submit itself, but in my case I'm using a method. In any case, it works fine for the creation (works as expected), and only refreshes when editing an existing record (both using the same code, only difference is the method itself and the loading of the page).